# Is it possible to include HTML code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic question, can I include HTML code in JS? (with `document.write`)

This is my HTML code:

```html
<li><a href="#" class="menulink">text</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="menulink">text</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="#" class="menulink">text</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="sub">text</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="topline"><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="sub">text</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="topline"><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#" class="sub">text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="sub">text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" class="menulink">text</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#" class="menulink">text</a></li>
```

And I want to include it in this JS code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML="";
}
```

Connect it by this code:

```
<p id="dropdown_menu"></p>
```

How can I do it?

*The full code is here* http://jsfiddle.net/tsnave/eSgWj/4/
thanks..

Comment: i changed the code... pleas help me...

Answer (score 16):

A different way of doing it is to put the HTML inside a script tag:

```
<script type="text/template" id="myHtml">
    <li class="topline"><a href="#">some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
</script>
```

Then you can get it into Javascript using

```
var myHtml = document.getElementById('myHtml').innerHTML;
```

or using one of several libraries which help you with this. Code inside a script tag with `type="text/template"` will not be interpreted or shown by the browser. The advantage of this approach over putting it straight into a string in Javascript is that it allows you to keep treating it as normal HTML in your editor, and it keeps the Javascript clean. See also [this post by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).

Comment: what is the difference between type="text/template" and type="text/Html" ?

Answer (score 12):

> can I include HTML code in JS?

If by that you mean can you output HTML via javascript then the answer is yes e.g.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = '<li class="topline"><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">some text </a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#"some text</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML='
    <li class="topline"><a href="#">some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
';
```

All I really did was switch the quotes to single quotes so the HTML attributes don't mess the string up. If you did need to put single quotes in the `innerHtml` string, you can escape them with backslash, ie: `innerHtml = ' Don\'t break me'`;

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML="<div>hello</div>"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML='<li class="topline"><a href="#">some text</a></li><li><a href="#">some text </a></li><li><a href="#">some text</a></li><li><a href="#">some text</a></li><li><a href="#"some text</a></li><li><a href="#">some text</a></li><li><a href="#">some text</a></li>';
}
```

Edited:

It should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = 
        '<li><a href="#" class="menulink">text</a></li>'
        +'<li><a href="#" class="menulink">text</a></li>'
        +'<li><a href="#" class="menulink">text</a><ul>'
        +'<li><a href="#" class="sub">text</a><ul>'
        +'<li class="topline"><a href="#">text</a></li>'
        +'<li><a href="#">text </a></li><li><a href="#">text</a></li>'
        +'<li><a href="#">text</a></li><li><a href="#">text</a></li>'
        +'<li><a href="#"text</a></li><li><a href="#">text</a></li></ul>'
        +'</li><li><a href="#" class="sub">text </a><ul>'
        +'<li class="topline"><a href="#">text</a></li>'
        +'<li><a href="#">text</a></li></ul></li>'
        +'<li><a href="#" class="sub">text</a></li>'
        +'<li><a href="#" class="sub">text</a></li>'
        +'</ul></li><li><a href="#" class="menulink">text</a></li>'
        +'<li><a href="#" class="menulink">text</a>';

}
```

Comment: I rolled-back the edit because JS doesn't support linebreaks in strings.

Comment: hi. thank you! i changes the code above and now your solution doesnt work... can you help me pleas?

Comment: make sure there is a html element with id="menu" and run this code after page loaded, modified the answer try it, should work.

Comment: can you  edit Please your code to match the current code which is above? I tried your first suggestion and the code did not work ...
I would love for help ..
Thank you!

Comment: the code  in the "class="menulink"" works good!!
but the other codes arn't working...
and your sokution works only if i change the JS code to :
   document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML
if not it won't work...
im really sorry for all these quastions but i am really need help
thanks for all!!

Comment: i just posted for concept, you can use "document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML" in both cease should work.

Comment: yes! here is the link. i want to put the html code of the dropdown menu into a JS code
http://jsfiddle.net/tsnave/eSgWj/4/

Comment: replace you ul#menu innerHTML before dropdown function fired.. http://jsfiddle.net/krishna_aim24/eSgWj/6/

Comment: this very harf for me. can you pleas write ther the correct code? thanks